# Prevent windows 7 from sleeping when installing updates

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, sleep

I have a laptop Windows 7 which is set to sleep when I close the lid. I would like to be able to close the lid when it is installing updates without it sleeping because it doesn't install the updates when it's sleeping. I know that I can go into power options and change this before it installs the updates and then change it back after but I would like to know if there is any way to make it automatically check if it is installing updates or not and not sleep if it is and sleep if it is not.

Answer (score -1):

Control Panel > Power Options > "Your Power Pan" > Choose what closing the lid does 
Choose your setting there.
If the option is not there, try Advanced Settings. This is how you do it manually, but no idea regarding automating it.

Comment: I know how to do it manually, I even mentioned this solution in my question. What I would like is a way to do it automatically.